# Details Table for Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-grid

I have been working on getting a kendo grid setup to read a XML file with products and license keys.

So far I have gotten the Main grid to read the products just fine, but I want to create a details table with the keys for that product.

XML Info

```
<YourKey>
    <Product_Key Name="Product">
        <Key ID="xxx" Type="Static" ClaimedDate="7/23/13">KEY DATA"</Key>
    </Product_Key>
    <Product_Key Name="Product">
        <Key ID="xxx" Type="Static" ClaimedDate="7/23/13">KEY DATA"</Key>
    </Product_Key>
 (****AND SO ON****)
</YourKey
```

The code for the grid I have so far is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.grid.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



 <div id="example2" class="k-content">
            <div id="grid2"></div>

            <script>


            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(
                    {
                        transport: {
                                read: "KeysExport.xml"                              
                        },
                        schema: {
                                type:"xml",
                                data: "/YourKey/Product_Key",
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        name: "@Name",
                                        //keyType: "/Key/@Type",
                                        //key: "/Key/text()"
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    });


                 $(document).ready(function () {
                 $("#grid2").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                height: 550,
                columns: [
                 { field: "name", title: "name" }
                       ] 
            });
        });
            </script>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Any help on getting the detail grid in would be greatly appreciated.  I am not a great js guy, and the Kendo documentation isn't what I am used to with other Telerik products.